# Unable to strip HTML tags from multibyte input

Tags: php, preg-replace, multibyte

I have a function which assist to strip out HTML tags from input as below.

**PHP**

```
function strip_html_tags2( $str ) 
    {
        $var_search = array(
            // Remove invisible content
            '@<head[^>]*?>.*?</head>@siu',
            '@<style[^>]*?>.*?</style>@siu',
            '@<script[^>]*?.*?</script>@siu',
            '@<object[^>]*?.*?</object>@siu',
            '@<embed[^>]*?.*?</embed>@siu',
            '@<applet[^>]*?.*?</applet>@siu',
            '@<noframes[^>]*?.*?</noframes>@siu',
            '@<noscript[^>]*?.*?</noscript>@siu',
            '@<noembed[^>]*?.*?</noembed>@siu',
            // Add line breaks before and after blocks
            '@</?((address)|(blockquote)|(center)|(del))@iu',
            '@</?((div)|(h[1-9])|(ins)|(isindex)|(p)|(pre))@iu',
            '@</?((dir)|(dl)|(dt)|(dd)|(li)|(menu)|(ol)|(ul))@iu',
            '@</?((table)|(th)|(td)|(caption))@iu',
            '@</?((form)|(button)|(fieldset)|(legend)|(input))@iu',
            '@</?((label)|(select)|(optgroup)|(option)|(textarea))@iu',
            '@</?((frameset)|(frame)|(iframe))@iu',
        );
        $var_replace = array(
            ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ',
            "\n\$0", "\n\$0", "\n\$0", "\n\$0", "\n\$0", "\n\$0",
            "\n\$0", "\n\$0",
        );
        //$str = html_entity_decode($str, ENT_QUOTES, 'UTF-8');
        $str = preg_replace("/&#?[a-z0-9]+;/i"," ", $str);
        $str = preg_replace( $var_search, $var_replace, $str );
        return strip_tags( $str );
    }
```

It's not working while I try to use on the content below and the result will be an empty string.

```
<p>If you’ve had a website up since at least the beginning of the year...</p>
```

It probably caused by the single quote but I have no idea on how to solve this.

Try copy and paste it into demo page below.

[Demo](http://generate-password.net/test/)

Any advice will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: I just tested this, and running that function on the input you gave results in an the same text, but with `<p>` and `</p>` replaced with `\n`. In other words, exactly what it sounds like you want. Check out this [**demo**](http://ideone.com/Ecu9e9).

Comment: your code is working as intended then what is the issue.

Comment: Its working if store the input into variable, but it's not working while input via POST. Added demo page above.

Comment: @wkyip Well, in that case, show how you're calling the function. Probably, you are using `$_POST` incorrectly. Without the code that calls the function, we would be guessing what's wrong. Also, FYI, if you reply to someone's comment, you should include their username in the comment (like I did with yours here). That way, it notifies them that you responded. Otherwise, they will not know that you said anything. I just happened to see your comment; otherwise, I would never have known about it.